# Can anyone explain why this sorting won't work?

Tags: python, sorting

For example if I have a list like this:

```
List1 =[7,6,9]
List1 = List1.sort()
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html - Sort the items of the list, in place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`, so you were actually assigning that return value to `List1`, i.e `None`.

```
>>> List1 =[7,6,9]
>>> repr(List1.sort())
'None'                     #return Value of list.sort
>>> List1                  #though list is sorted
[6, 7, 9]
```

On the other hand the built-in function `sorted` returns a **new** sorted list:

```
>>> List1 =[7,6,9]
>>> sorted(List1)
[6, 7, 9]
>>> List1           #List1 is not affected
[7, 6, 9]
```

You can assign back the result of `sorted` to `List1`, but this makes no sense as `list.sort`will do the same thing and in lesser time.

```
>>> List1 = sorted(List1)
>>> List1
[6, 7, 9]
```

Though the above code was similar to `list.sort`, but actually it's a bit different because it returns new list. Example:

```
>>> List1 =[7,6,9]
>>> List2 = List1         # both List1, List2 point to the same object [7, 6, 9]
>>> List1.sort()          # sort List1 in-place, affects the original object
>>> List1, List2
([6, 7, 9], [6, 7, 9])    # both variables still point to the same list

>>> List1 =[7,6,9]
>>> List2 = List1         #same as above
>>> List1 = sorted(List1) #sorted returns a new list, so List1 now points to this new list 
>>> List1, List2          #List2 is still unchanged
([6, 7, 9], [7, 6, 9])
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> from random import shuffle

>>> lis = range(10**5)
>>> shuffle(lis)
>>> %timeit lis.sort()
1 loops, best of 3: 9.9 ms per loop

>>> lis = range(10**5)
>>> shuffle(lis)
>>> %timeit sorted(lis)
1 loops, best of 3: 95.9 ms per loop
```

So, `sorted` should be used only when you don't want to affect the original list and want to assign the sorted version of that list to some other variable.

Apart from lists other data-structures like **set**, **tuples**, **dicts**,etc don't have their own `.sort()` method, so `sorted` is the only thing you can use there.

```
>>> s = {1,5,3,6}  # set
>>> sorted(s)
[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

help on `sorted`:

```
>>> print sorted.__doc__
sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

Answer (score 6):

[`.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) sorts the list in place. It does not return the new list. Infact, as it doesn't return anything by default, it returns `None`.

If you want the sorted list returned, you can use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
List1 = sorted(List1)
```

Comment: It doesn't normally make sense to use `List1 = sorted(List1)` in place of `List1.sort()`. The only difference is that it decouples the original from the sorted list, but if List1 is the only reference to the List, the unsorted one will just be GC'd

Comment: You can add extra parameters to `.sort()` either.