# Why this Python expression doesn't produce expected result?

Tags: python, syntax, expression

This code snippet:

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
a.sort()
```

produces `[1, 2, 3]` list. Why

```
[3, 2, 1].sort()
```

doesn't produce the same result? Is there a "one-liner" to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 
`sorted_array = sorted([2,3,1])`

Comment: Accepted this answer because it offers the one-liner I asked for. Semicolon is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [3, 2, 1].sort()
```

It does sort this list object but as the number of references(variables pointing) to this list are **0**, so it is garbage collected.(i.e we can't access this list anymore)

Coming to your first question, `list.sort()` sorts a list in-place and returns `None`.

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 1]
>>> a.sort()    
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you want `a` to stay as it is, use `sorted` and assign the result back to some variable.

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 1]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: No need to invoke garbage collection or reference counts. `list.sort` returns None, so the list might as well stick around forever.

Comment: Is there a good reason for `list.sort()` to return `None` instead of the list, where `b = [3, 2, 1].sort()` would work?

Comment: @PaulJurczak all in-place modification operations on python lists return `None`, there's no point of the returning the same object that is being modified in-place. Use `sorted` if you want a new copy. I wrote a detailed answer related to this that you might want to read. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141255/can-anyone-explain-why-this-sorting-wont-work/17141264#17141264

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The point would be to pipeline (apply) several functions to it in concise manner: `list.sort().doThis().doThat().doSomethingElse()`

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` is a method that sorts an existing list therefore returning `None`

`sorted` is a builtin function that creates a new sorted list from its input and returns it.